# Spring boot: minimum input < max input in html

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

How can I precise that the max price must be greater than the minimum price?

```html
<div class="mb-3">
    <label for="min_price" class="form-label">Min price</label>
    <input type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control" id="max_price" name="min_price">
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
    <label for="max_price" class="form-label">Max price</label>
    <input type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control" id="min_price" name="max_price">
</div>
```

Comment: do you mean verifying it on the user interface level (browser), adding a comment about it or veryfying on the backend after submit? or something else?

Comment: Directly at the browser in the html

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot is a backend framework and thymeleaf is a templating engine for it. They don't have support for such features, you would need some javascript action on that one.